# Openpyxl - Setting the number format code

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I tried to set the number_format in openpyxl but it doesn't work in the new version 2.6.0. I tried the following codes to set the format in a cell:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename="test.xlsx")
ws = wb["test_sheet"] 
ws.cell(row=3, column=1).number_format = "hh:mm"
ws["A3"].number_format = 'hh:mm'
```

I also tried it with styles but without any luck...

Comment: *"without any luck..."*: [Edit] your Question and show the result? How did you verify this?

Comment: Have you tried Saving the workbook at the bottom of the script?